# Change column name in query to parameter value in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that analyses the difference in costs between two select years. So I have 3 queries in total like this;

---

qry_Comp_Year1 (CrossTab)
Providers
Cost
Quarter
FinYear = [Forms]![frm_Comparison]![cmb_comp_year1]
Total: Cost Sum

SQL

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![frm_Comparison]![cmb_comp_year1] Text ( 255 );
TRANSFORM Sum(tbl_comparison_data.Cost) AS SumOfCost
SELECT tbl_comparison_data.Service, tbl_comparison_data.FinYear, Sum(tbl_comparison_data.cost) AS Total
FROM tbl_comparison_data
WHERE (((tbl_comparison_data.FinYear)=[Forms]![frm_Comparison]![cmb_comp_year1]))
GROUP BY tbl_comparison_data.Service, tbl_comparison_data.FinYear
PIVOT tbl_comparison_data.Quarter;
```

---

qry_Comp_Year2 (CrossTab)
Providers
Cost
Quarter
FinYear = [Forms]![frm_Comparison]![cmb_comp_year2]
Total: Cost Sum

SQL

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![frm_Comparison]![cmb_comp_year2] Text ( 255 );
TRANSFORM Sum(tbl_comparison_data.Cost) AS SumOfCost
SELECT tbl_comparison_data.Service, tbl_comparison_data.FinYear, Sum(tbl_comparison_data.cost) AS Total
FROM tbl_comparison_data
WHERE (((tbl_comparison_data.FinYear)=[Forms]![frm_Comparison]![cmb_comp_year2]))
GROUP BY tbl_comparison_data.Service, tbl_comparison_data.FinYear
PIVOT tbl_comparison_data.Quarter;
```

---

Query 3 (CrossTab)
Service
Cost (column names: qry_Comp_Year1.Total qry_Comp_Year2.Total)
Difference qry_Comp_Year2.Total - qry_Comp_Year1.Total

SQL

```
SELECT qry_Comp_Providers.Service, qry_Comp_Year1.Total, qry_Comp_Year2.Total, nz([qry_Comp_Year2.Total])-nz([qry_Comp_Year1.Total]) AS Difference
FROM qry_Comp_Year2 RIGHT JOIN (qry_Comp_Year1 RIGHT JOIN qry_Comp_Providers ON qry_Comp_Year1.Service = qry_Comp_Providers.Service) ON qry_Comp_Year2.Service = qry_Comp_Providers.Service;
```

---

OUTPUT

```
Service qry_Comp_Year1.Total    qry_Comp_Year2.Total    Difference  
Clean   225                              340               115  
Service 678                              374              -304  
Update  400                              410               10
```

---

SAMPLE DATA

```
ID  Service Cost    Quarter FinYear  
1   Clean   100       Q1    2015-16  
2   Update  250       Q2    2015-16  
3   Update  150       Q1    2015-16  
4   Clean   125       Q3    2015-16  
5   Service 178       Q4    2015-16  
6   Service 500       Q2    2015-16  
7   Clean   175       Q1    2016-17  
8   Update  225       Q2    2016-17  
9   Update  185       Q1    2016-17  
10  Clean   165       Q3    2016-17  
11  Service 187       Q4    2016-17  
12  Service 187       Q2    2016-17
```

However, when you look at query 3 I would like cost columns to have the year as the column heading so it is clear which years have been selected. Is this possible?

Comment: Edit question to provide SQL statements and sample source data.

Comment: @June7 Have done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the final output doesn't use the quarterly data, a single CROSSTAB can return the yearly totals with the year column as column headers. However this means the column header names will be dynamic, making it impractical to build a stable query or report with the CROSSTAB as source to calculate the difference.

So no, I don't see a practical way to get the years in the CROSSTAB column headers but don't really need to. Suggest you build a report based on Query3 and have two textboxes on the report reference the form controls.